# Combine two integer vectors

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have two integer vectors. First one contains all of my userIds (lets say the count=100) and second vector contains users that did something. I need a result array with the size of 100  and if that user is in the second list the value will be true, if not the value will be false.

Let me draw this:

```
userVector  filteredUserVector  theResultArray
1001        1001                true
1002        1002                true
1003        1004                false
1004        1006                true
1005                            false
1006                            true
1007                            false
```

And I'm doing this with a code like this:

```
 var theResultArray = (FROM user IN userVector  
                              JOIN login IN filteredUserVector ON user equals login INTO prodGroup
                              FROM item IN prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              SELECT item != 0).ToArray();
```

This works. But my problem is:

The first vectors have 185569 integer value and im doing this in a for loop. In every loop my `filteredUserVector` changes. My loop count is 40.000 and in 30k s it crashes with memory exception.

the code whole code block:

```
loop starts:
    var filteredUserVector=anotherDataSource.select(some where conditions)
     var theResultArray = (FROM user IN userVector  
                              JOIN login IN filteredUserVector ON user equals login INTO prodGroup
                              FROM item IN prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              SELECT item != 0).ToArray();

    ..some code..

    bigStore.Add(theResultArray)
loop ends
```

I hope I could explain my problem. 
How can I combine in a way that I want efficiently?

Comment: Are the lists in memory or in a database or something similar? Also, you're saying that "in every loop my filtereduservector changes" yet the code you've shown does not show any such changes. Can you please post the real code and not just "code like this"?

Comment: the last value should be `false`, right?

Comment: The lists in memory. In every loop filteredUserVector's values may change  actually with nothing extra. yeah sorry the last one should be false btw

Comment: What do you mean filteredUserVector changes?

Comment: i wrote the loop code block. You can see it above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashSet<int>` and *Linq*:

```
int[] userVector = new int[] {
  1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007,
};

int[] filteredUserVector = new int[] {
  1001, 1002, 1004, 1006
};

....

HashSet<int> filtered = new HashSet<int>(filteredUserVector);

Boolean[] theResultArray = userVector
  .Select(item => filtered.Contains(item))
  .ToArray();

// Test:
// True, True, False, True, False, True, False
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", theResultArray));
```